# Excel formula to return column header values based on following rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to come up with a formula that will return values of headers for each row that has one more more "x". (As seen in the "results" column below)

Can this be done without use of VBA or other external scripts?

|  | t1 | t2 | t3 |  | results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | x |  |  | t1,t2 |
| b | x | x | x |  | t1,t2,t3 |
| c |  |  | x |  | t3 |

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSNpk.png)

Comment: Welcome! You can try something like as `{=TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF($B2:$D2="";"";$B$1:$D$1))}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF($B2:$D2="x",$B$1:$D$1,""))
```

[image]